# Python lambda function doesn't work in correct manner

Tags: python, lambda

I'm a noob of Python. These are my variables:

```
>>> y=1

>>> i=5
```

I use the lambda function:

```
>>> (lambda y: y*i)(i)

>>> 25
```

Why the output is 25 if y=1 and i=5???????

If I use numbers:

```
>>> (lambda y: 1*i)(i)

>>> 5
```

Is this normal? Why the y is 5 in the first case, and 1 in the other case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've passed `i` as the first argument. This means that `y` in the lambda is bound to the value in `i`. And then you multiply `y` by `i`. This results in 5 * 5, or 25.

Answer (score 2):

These are actually working in correct manner. Your first lambda expressions is similar to:

```
def f(y):
    return y * i
```

As you can see `y` is the argument of the function. And it is returning the `argument` * `i` (whatever `i`'s value is).

So `(lambda y: y*i)(i)` is like calling `f(i)`. Now you have already set `i`'s value as 5. So it's basically `f(5)` and returning you the value (5 * 5) -> 25.

The second expression is similar to:

```
def g(y):
     return 1 * y
```

You are passing `i` in `g()`. `i`'s value is 5, So it's like calling `g(5)` and it's returning you the value (1 * 5) -> 5 .